# SVG - Custom font not applies

Tags: css, svg, fonts

Here is my svg file, I am trying to use the custom font. But not works. any one help me?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="79" height="48" viewBox="0 0 79 48"><defs><style>@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular';
    src:url('MyriadPro-Regular.woff');
}.a{fill:none;}.b{clip-path:url(#a);}.c{fill:#fff;font-size:14px;letter-spacing:0.01em;}</style><clipPath id="a"><rect class="a" width="79" height="48"/></clipPath></defs><g class="b"><text font-family="MyriadPro-Regular" class="c" transform="translate(0 13)"><tspan x="0" y="0">ASSESSMENT</tspan><tspan x="0" y="16">OPERATING</tspan><tspan x="0" y="32">SYSTEM</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

`MyriadPro-Regular.woff` - font nested in the same folder.

Comment: Most likely a bad path to the font file - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/how-do-i-use-a-custom-font-in-an-svg-image-on-my-site

Comment: @GrzegorzT. - what you mean? the font is nested on same folder

Comment: I downloaded this font and checked it out. And it looks like it works, I also used a different font and the same. I tested for chrome, opera, firefox, vivaldi, edge and IE11 
Does this font not appear, does not you see any symptom, error?

Comment: @GrzegorzT. - I do not see any error. Is there any workaround to fix this issue?